# Laravel Elixir: Use wildcard without combining

Tags: css, sass, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have a folder, in `resources/assets/sass` that have 2 files `1.scss` and `2.scss`

I would want to do:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
 .sass('*.scss', './public/css/');
});
```

And for that to generate `1.css` and `2.css`

I actually have more than 2 files and that's why I don't want to write them one by one. Any way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this as well. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Since you can write any JavaScript in the Gulpfile, you can use the 'glob' module to get the filenames, like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var glob   = require('glob');
var path   = require('path');

elixir(function (mix) {
    for (let file of glob.sync('resources/assets/sass/*.scss')) {
        mix.sass(path.basename(file), './public/css/');
    }
});
```

It can be more advanced if needed - e.g. I'm using it with versioning and custom paths (and ES2015 syntax):

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
const glob   = require('glob');
const path   = require('path');

elixir(mix =>
{
    let build_files = [];

    for (let theme of glob.sync('resources/assets/sass/themes/*/')) {
        theme = path.basename(theme);

        mix.sass(`themes/${theme}/app.scss`, `public/css/${theme}/app.css`);
        build_files.push(`css/${theme}/app.css`);
    }

    mix.version(build_files);
});
```